# Instagram how to get user id from access token using javascript?

Tags: javascript, instagram

Is there any Instagram JS SDK to get user id using access token?

Comment: If you don't want to send a webrequest, you can also try to [decode the jwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552003/how-to-decode-jwt-token-in-javascript-without-using-a-library) and get the id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter this url in your browser with the users name you want to find and your access token

```
> https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=[USERNAME]&access_token=[ACCESS
 TOKEN]
```

you can find more information [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171122061459/https://jelled.com/instagram/lookup-user-id)