# Where to find auth.token data, inside firebase objects

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am using `signInWithCustomToken`, after authentication I can not find where is stored my custom claims data which I have set in the server side(createCustomToken).

I can see them in firebase rules via auth.token, but how can I access them  through firebase objects from within my javascript code.

Comment: have you tried this? `var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;`  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

Comment: yes I tried, but was not able to find my custom properties inside currentUser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The information in the token is not automatically available to your application code. But it is embedded in the token, so you can decode it yourself:

```
function parseJwt (token) {
    var base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
    var base64 = base64Url.replace('-', '+').replace('_', '/');
    return JSON.parse(window.atob(base64));
};

var user = firebase.auth().currentUser
user.getToken().then(data => {
    console.log(parseJwt(data));
});
```

The function to parse the JWT comes from this question: [How to decode jwt token in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552003/how-to-decode-jwt-token-in-javascript)

You'll note that it doesn't verify that the ID token is valid. That seems fine to me in client-side code, since the information will be used by the user themselves anyway. But if you do want to verify the token, you'll have to use a more involved method.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why that information is not included in the user object, for me it would make sense that after `signInWithCustomToken` all custom fields would be available inside my user or auth() object.