# Firebase Authentication using Custom Token : Is there a way by which I can associate username and email with the custom token

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am creating custom token on my application server for authenticated users, however when I sign in using custom token from my client app(java script), the user object is having null values for following :
    - "displayName": null
    - "photoURL": null
    - "email": null

I wish if I can set above values while creating the custom token. I do not see any way by which I can do this : maybe its not even supported for custom tokens.

Comment: You can specify any values you want in a custom token, except the [reserved values specified here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdks). Those values will then be available in the security rules for your Firebase Database and Firebase Storage. But the values are not available on the client. To get access to your values there, you will have to decode them from the JWT yourself. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39917020/where-to-find-auth-token-data-inside-firebase-objects/39918177#39918177