# Access Firebase Custom Token claims from the Web SDK

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

If I have a custom token with certain claims and I sign in to Firebase using it, is there any way to access those claims from inside app, using the Web SDK?

For example, if my custom token is like this

```
{
 :iss => $service_account_email,
 :sub => $service_account_email,
 :aud => "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit",
 :iat => now_seconds,
 :exp => now_seconds+(60*60), # Maximum expiration time is one hour
 :uid => uid,
 :claims => {:premium_account => is_premium_account}
}
```

I would like to know if there is something like (from inside the app):

```
firebase.auth.token.claims.premium_account
```

I'm not finding anything like this in the docs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39917020/where-to-find-auth-token-data-inside-firebase-objects

Comment: Thanks @bojeil. So It looks like it's not accesible from the sdk...

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you want [`getIdTokenResult`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getIdTokenResult):

```
await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdTokenResult()
```

Answer (score 1):

`claims` is embedded in the token.

Here is an example code to extract the claims from the token using [`jwt-decode`](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode) on a web client:

```
import jwt_decode from './jwt-decode';

firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken().then((token) => {
    console.log(token);
    console.log(jwt_decode(token));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation on it: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

I think the gist of it, is once you have custom claims appended to a user via backend code (admin sdk OR firebase functions), you can base64 decode the currentUser token.
The documentation references a mozilla article on javascript base64 decoding: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

You can JSON.parse the decoded token and your custom claims will show up there. The documentation is pretty good about it.