# Library for decoding JWT on client-side

Tags: javascript, jwt

I'm working on a website that stores JWT token inside cookies. What I want to do is, create Javascript that decodes the token and extracts the value I need and pass it on to the another Javascript written by my co-worker. My question is, is there client-side javascript library for JWT token decoding that I can import from my script?

Comment: Check this: https://jwt.io/#libraries Look for Javascript section

Comment: @MikeCheel 's comment is very useful if you need to verify a signed JWT or decode a crypted JWT. But if you just want o read an uncrypted JWT, you just need to base64 decode it as described in the answer from  bhspencer

Comment: Be careful, the user can tamper with that and since you don't have access to the shared secret on the backend, it won't be reliable ever.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

EDIT: It has come to my attention that this answer is incorrect. Please see this answer instead
[How to decode jwt token in javascript without using a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552003/how-to-decode-jwt-token-in-javascript-without-using-a-library)

A JWT is just a dot separated base64 encoded string. You just need to split on the dots and then use atob() to decode. You don't need an external library.

e.g.

```js
var jwt = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ";

var tokens = jwt.split(".");

console.log(JSON.parse(atob(tokens[0])));
console.log(JSON.parse(atob(tokens[1])));
```

Comment: Thanks but I suppose it won't work with UTF, would it?

Comment: @user30646 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding#The_.22Unicode_Problem.22

Comment: This is missing validation. You should validate JWT's, anyone can create them, but only the person that knows the secret can create a token signed with the secret.

Comment: The OP asked "What I want to do is, create Javascript that decodes the token and extracts the value I need". Of course it is also necessary to verify the signature on the token but that is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: @FastDeveloper Validation occurs on server side, a secret on client side would defeat the purpose of jwt

Comment: Not necessarily. The client could be verifying the token is from who they say they are with a public key.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode : jwt-decode is a small browser library that helps decoding JWTs token which are Base64Url encoded.