# How to get user role from jwt token

Tags: angular, token, jwt

In server side I have those code to login:

```
return jsonify({'email': email, 'token': create_token(email, isAdmin, password)})
```

In client side I need code to check login and isAdmin.

```
isLogged() {
if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser') &&
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')).email) {
  return true;
}
return false;
}

isAdmin(){
  //???
}
```

How can I get user role from token?

Comment: Have you tried decoding it to see the claims? [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552003/how-to-decode-jwt-token-in-javascript)

Comment: I have secret key only in server side, not client.

Comment: You do not need the secret key to decode the payload. It is a json object  base64url encoded

Comment: Maybe you can give me same example of decoding payload?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Say you had this JWT ([example from here](https://jwt.io/))

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ
```

You could use [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38552302/6894075) to decode it:

```js
let jwt = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ'

let jwtData = jwt.split('.')[1]
let decodedJwtJsonData = window.atob(jwtData)
let decodedJwtData = JSON.parse(decodedJwtJsonData)

let isAdmin = decodedJwtData.admin

console.log('jwtData: ' + jwtData)
console.log('decodedJwtJsonData: ' + decodedJwtJsonData)
console.log('decodedJwtData: ' + decodedJwtData)
console.log('Is admin: ' + isAdmin)
```

Comment: This solution definitely works, as I just tested it myself. Never the less, I feel no confidence using *window.atob(...)* as it seems so... not Angular'ish. It resembles a bit the old kind of programming with JS. It might simply be just me being ignorant, though. Is there a more TypeScript'ish syntax for that operation? Especially if it's packaged in JWT related library. After all - all the JWT tokens will contain of the three parts where we only want to see the decoded version of the middle one, right?

Comment: I think the use of atob is fine.  Someone can re-implement atob in typescript and put it up as an npm package but I can't think what problem that would solve.  The only issue you could run into is that browsers could implement atob differently but I think if they can't encode/decode base64 you probably have bigger issues with that browser.