# json data extract nested objects from _body - Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to get value of a token but I get error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined`

[image]

## code

```
//Below code gives the output shown below with black color text
data.text()

// I am interested in fetching token value which is nested inside success keyword, below code fails to get the token
var abc = data.text();
abc['success'].token
```

Comment: It seams that `abc` is a `String`, not an `Object`. So `abc['success']` doesn't fit the need (it's null). Maybe you should use JSON's parser or change the type of returned data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let abc = JSON.parse(data.text());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var abc = (JSON.parse(data._body)).success.token;
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code is for reading JWT form js

```
function parseJwt (token) {
            var base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
            var base64 = base64Url.replace('-', '+').replace('_', '/');
            return JSON.parse(window.atob(base64));
        };
```

[How to decode jwt token in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552003/how-to-decode-jwt-token-in-javascript)