# JWT decoding working in React Native but not for React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jwt

So when you decode the following in https://jwt.io/  it says it has a header named 'token' which has the token when you re-decode it you can access the payload.

Normally in RN I can access the payload containing token using this.props.user.token but in React the 'token' property is not there as it is not an javascript object but a string but I use the same API to my backend.

```
eyJ0b2tlbiI6ImV5SmhiR2NpT2lKSVV6STFOaUlzSW5SNWNDSTZJa3BYVkNKOS5leUpwWkhCaGMzTWlPaUl6WkRFME1ERmlNQzFtTkdWakxURXhaVGN0WVdReE15MHpaRGRsTUdZME9EUmlaR0k2TVRsaU4yTmpNREUyWVRVeU1ERTRNemt3TmpsbU56aGxNV0pqTXpBMk4yUTBZalJqTVRrNE1HTTBPV05tWkRsak9XWTRNV1F4Tm1VMllUbGhaR1JrTVNJc0ltbGhkQ0k2TVRVeE5UY3lNalF6TkgwLlg0dGUxRmhzbGJlcW5Id3RCQ2NOMHF5Zk9vb2tvdVN2TXRlLVBUTUtrMHcifQ==
```

I tried to decode it using

```
var decoded = jwt.decode(response.data);
```

but decoded is null, what can I do?

Answer (score 16):

You can use any npm module for decoding like :

`npm install jwt-decode`

```
var jwtDecode = require('jwt-decode');

var token = 'eyJ0eXAiO.../// jwt token';

var decoded = jwtDecode(token);
console.log(decoded);
```

For further info [check here](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode)

Comment: I told you it's not working for my case you still reply with the same code

Comment: [follow this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552003/how-to-decode-jwt-token-in-javascript)

Comment: is any liabrary which is compatible with this for react native mobile application

Comment: Does not work with node <=18

Answer (score 1):

It's work well:

var jwtDecode = require('jwt-decode');

var decoded = jwtDecode(testString, { body: true });

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Buffer } from "buffer"

const token = 'xxx.xxx.xxx';

const parts: Buffer[] = token.split('.').map((part: string): Buffer => {
            return Buffer.from(part.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/'), 'base64');
        });
const payload = JSON.parse(parts[1].toString());
```