# Firebase UI returns idToken that supposedly is not correctly encoded in Facebook login for some users

Tags: facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am developing an app that verify the custom claims for a user using the following code:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken().then(idToken => {
      // Parse the ID token.
      const payload = JSON.parse(window.atob(idToken.split(".")[1]));
      // Confirm the user is an Admin.
      if (!!payload["admin"]) { // continue
```

But I realised that some users that logged in using Facebook receives the error below:

**DOMException: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.**

These users don't have any custom claim attributed in the app. It looks like that some Facebook's users already receives an idToken from login that is not compatible with atob function. It's not happen to all Facebook users.

Would someone know why some users is receiving an idToken when log in Firebase UI through Facebook ?

Comment: Try this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552003/how-to-decode-jwt-token-in-javascript