# How can I get the data from token

Tags: jwt, lumen

I am trying to get data included in a JWT Token with Angular 6.

I can do the login action, and return the token with Lumen 5.6 - tymondesigns/jwt-auth

But then, when I print it in JS, I get:

```
iat: 1531073200         
iss: "https://api.kz-api.test/auth/login"         
jti: "taCmXQoo0jWs4y7t"         
nbf: 1531073200         
prv: "87e0af1ef9fd15812fdec97153a14e0b047546aa"         
sub: 1
```

I thought I should have the user object in ‘sub’ array as it identifies the subject of the JWT, but I can only find 1….
What’s wrong with my code:

```
/**
 * Authenticate a user and return the token if the provided credentials are correct.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function authenticate()
{
    // Find the user by email
    $user = User::where('email', $this->request->input('email'))->first();
    if (!$user) {
        return response()->json('login.wrong_email', HttpResponse::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
    $credentials = Input::only('email', 'password');
    if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return response()->json('login.wrong_password', HttpResponse::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
    return response()->json(compact('token'), HttpResponse::HTTP_ACCEPTED);
}
```

Comment: Is that print out at the top your entire response packet? Also, it's bothering me that you're returning specific errors for wrong password and wrong email, you should never do that.

Comment: Yes, I only return the token. I could also return the user object, but I tought it was contained inside token... And as for specific codes, why shouldn't I do it ?

Comment: I mean for the `login.wrong_password` and `login.wrong_email`, it's best practice to rather return one error for both, like `login.failed`. If you return a specific error for each, a hacker can tell that the email is correct, but the password isn't and can then brute force that account. In your response do you get a valid JWT token?

Comment: Yes my token seems valid!

Comment: Ok, you can decode your token as per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552003/how-to-decode-jwt-token-in-javascript

Comment: I think I have no problem decoding my token, as in my question, I print the result of decoded token. Problem is I have a lack of information when decoding token.