# How to decode jwt token in POSTMAN?

Tags: jwt, postman

I want to decode jwt token that I received using Postman and implement it in REST API. How can I do that? I saw people posted code to decode the jwt token (reference: [How to decode jwt token in javascript without using a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552003/how-to-decode-jwt-token-in-javascript-without-using-a-library)) but I dont understand how to do it in postman? What url needed to decode the jwt? What headers, authorisation needed?

Comment: It's quite unclear what you really want. Decode in Postman? What's the purpose? Click on [edit] to add more information to your question.

Comment: @jps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552003/how-to-decode-jwt-token-in-javascript-without-using-a-library this is the reference. I wanted to use the code here but not sure how to use this in postman

Comment: Good one. This is useful if you want to run tests on the claims in the JWT, like to make sure that certain claims are present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postman supports cryptojs library : https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#using-external-libraries

Add below example to postman test script:

```
let jwt = `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJ0b3B0YWwuY29tIiwiZXhwIjoxNDI2NDIwODAwLCJodHRwOi8vdG9wdGFsLmNvbS9qd3RfY2xhaW1zL2lzX2FkbWluIjp0cnVlLCJjb21wYW55IjoiVG9wdGFsIiwiYXdlc29tZSI6dHJ1ZX0.UsrGn95rk5DStcC_WwIr3WIv5rHe2IApX56I58l8uyo`

a = jwt.split('.');


//a.forEach(function (val) {
    var words = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(a[1]);
    var textString = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(words);

    console.log(textString)
//})
```

**Output:**

[image]

The hmacSHA256 is not an encryption algorithm but an Hashing algorithm so there is no way to decode it as hashing is one-way function.

as the last part  is in the form

```
HMACSHA256 of ( base64(header) + "." + base64(body) )
```

you can  try creating it and equating both are equal

Answer (score 6):

You can manually parse using `atob` function that decodes a Base64 string. (https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/atob)

And it's available on Postman scripts.

Something like this:

```js
// Sample JWT
let jwt = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c'

let [jwtHeader, jwtPayload, jwtSignature] = jwt.split('.')

let jwtPayloadJsonString = atob(jwtPayload)

console.log(jwtPayloadJsonString)

let jwtPayloadJson = JSON.parse(jwtPayloadJsonString)

console.log(jwtPayloadJson)
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on PDHide’s answer, I came up with this ready-to-use snippet for Postman:

```js
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

let [header, payload, signature] = jsonData.access_token.split('.');

function decode(x) {
    let wordArray = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(x);
    let str = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(wordArray);
    return JSON.parse(str);
}

console.log("Header: ", decode(header));
console.log("Payload: ", decode(payload));
```

See [this](https://jwt.io/introduction) link for more information on the three parts of a JSON Web Token (header, payload and signature).

Answer (score 1):

This approach takes it one step further and uses the visualizer tab in postman to create a custom view to display any information you want to see:

https://medium.com/@jeff.heienickle/how-to-decode-a-json-web-token-in-postman-5312b3434462

Answer (score 0):

https://jwt.io/ if you'd like, which can solve your problem, you can also download some plugins if you use any IDE

Comment: I need to implement it in my API flow so I cant use jwt.io website

Answer (score 0):

using CryptoJS

```js
const payloadRaw = jwt.split('.')[1]
const payloadBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(payloadRaw);
const payload = JSON.parse(payloadBase64.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add, that if you want some value(email in this case) of the token to be saved as a variable in postman, you can add

pm.globals.set('email',jwtPayloadJson.email);

and then used anywhere as {{email}}