# How can i use Simple JWT for custom User Model

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am managing my User Model (for customers), but i don't know how can i use simple-jwt for my Customer Model with it's custom Login View.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Customer(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
   password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and also, i want to manage my customer session by saving the Refresh Token,
can anyone please tell me how can i achieve that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some research, I came to the conclusion that Simple JWT doesn't have any special support for user models that are not derived from `AbstactUserModel`.

It means if you are managing the **Customer** model, either you need to extend it from `AbstactUserModel` or you should use jwt instead of Simple jwt.

Comment: so you mean that if we use 2 kinds of User Model, we cannot use SImpe JWT for this purpose?

Answer (score 4):

First install simple jwt with the command
`pip install djangorestframework-simplejwt`
You must then configure your django project to use the libary with following option in `settings.py`

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        ...
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )
    ...
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,
    'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': False,

    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': settings.SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
    'AUDIENCE': None,
    'ISSUER': None,

    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
    'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',

    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',

    'JTI_CLAIM': 'jti',

    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
}
```

In your root `urls.py` add the following

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (
    TokenObtainPairView,
    TokenRefreshView,
)

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    ...
]
```

Simple JWT by default only sends user id in the token. You can customize it further to send more information in your `serializers.py` by doing the following

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
class CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    """Customizes JWT default Serializer to add more information about user"""
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super().get_token(user)
        token['name'] = user.name
        token['email'] = user.email
        token['is_superuser'] = user.is_superuser
        token['is_staff'] = user.is_staff

        return token
```

Then in your `views.py` add the following

```
from users import serializers
class CustomTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    # Replace the serializer with your custom
    serializer_class = serializers.CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

You can [read more here](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

To check out the JWT content, we can use JWT.io: [here](https://jwt.io/)

In case you are using Javascript frameworks or vanilla JS, you can use a function like this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552003/how-to-decode-jwt-token-in-javascript-without-using-a-library)

Comment: good explanation. Can you maybe explain how you would decode the extra fields you have added to your custom token?

Comment: @Lobbel depends on the where you are consuming the API. If using ReactJS you can use this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode or you can even a look at your token here https://jwt.io/

Comment: can we claim user username instead of user Id from jwt token ??

Answer (score 0):

I could fix this problem adding `'rest_framework_simplejwt'` to `INSTALLED_APPS` after the app that has the custom user model.

Comment: are you replacing the default django model with new one, or you using 2 model for 2 kind of user?

Comment: I was replacing the user model with a new one

Answer (score 0):

in your views.py file, import this

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
```

next, create a refresh token in def post - the one you use for logging in

```
def post(self, request):
    ...
    refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
    ...
```

return the generated refresh token and access token in the response body

```
return Response(
    {
        'refresh': str(refresh),
        'access': str(refresh.access_token),
    },
    status = status.HTTP_200_OK
)
```

What I have suggested is a simple and super basic implementation of what I believe you are looking for. I got it from [here](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/creating_tokens_manually.html). But if you want a better and more customized, neater implementation, refer [this article](https://dev.to/a_atalla/django-rest-framework-custom-jwt-authentication-5n5).

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to create the token manually using simple jwt

from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken

def get_tokens_for_user(user):
refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)

```
return {
    'refresh': str(refresh),
    'access': str(refresh.access_token),
}
```

you have the documentations here https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/creating_tokens_manually.html