# React google login using react-oauth

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-google-login

I have a react app ( typescript ) and want to integrate google authentication.

The authentication test works, but needs to extend the functionality

It just logs info to console

```
const responseMessage = (response: any) => {
    console.log(response);
};
const errorMessage = (error) => { //this is commented in typescript
    console.log(error);
};
```

Because the example is javascript, it does not fit in typescript model

> https://blog.logrocket.com/guide-adding-google-login-react-app/

I had to sacrifice  onError={errorMessage} from the below, as the function expects type to be specified for "error" and not accepting ? ( not specifying type or specifying :any both are error )

> < GoogleLogin onSuccess={responseMessage}  />

Question:

How can I write real onSuccess to navigate to a proper page (or same page with signin changing to logout ) and also fix my onError

Edit:
Initially I have login button, and after login I am still having that button. I am new to react and typescript, so struggling to beautify my page to give the feel to the user that the login task is complete, and remove/hide that button (Sign in as... after success login). I thought it will be out of the box, but looks like I have use localStorage and toggle

[image]

Comment: The react-google-login package is deprecated. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login Any reason why you still want to use it? Did you try https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-oauth/google?

Comment: Hi, may be you are mistaken by "tag", otherwise using react-oauth only see logrocket link also

Comment: I have answered for the errorMessage part. Can you give more context on what exactly you want to achieve in responseMessage? For navigation to different page you can use something like useHistory API

Answer (score 0):

The type declaration of `GoogleLogin` are as following:

```
onSuccess: (credentialResponse: CredentialResponse) => void;
onError?: () => void;
```

This means that `onError` method does not take any parameter. Try writing errorMessage as follows:

```
const errorMessage = () => {
    // Your steps
};
```

You can write responseMessage as follows:

```
import { CredentialResponse } from '@react-oauth/google';

const responseMessage = (response: CredentialResponse) => {
    console.log(response);
};
```

Comment: sure the signature of onError is empty, which means I have to write string like "Login Failed" . The answer I am looking for is to fill my gaps as asked in "Question". Example - how to decode my token  and move to a page . just fixed the typescript issue using dataCredentials class as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68524360/how-can-i-decode-a-google-oauth-2-0-jwt-credential-token   Now I have a good token const userObject: dataCredential = jwtDecode(response.credential);  localStorage is also utilised. see new screenshot of my problem

Comment: You can conditionally render the login UI based on whether userObject is available.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will post my full detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

This is how I updated my code

> import { jwtDecode } from "jwt-decode";

> import { dataCredential } from "../../common/dataCredentials";

```
  const responseMessage = (response: any) => {
    const userObject: dataCredential = jwtDecode(response.credential);
    
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(userObject));

    setProfile(userObject);
//I initially wanted to navigate, but decided to stay on the same page
    // client.createIfNotExists(doc).then(() => {
    //   navigate("/", { replace: true });
    // });
  };

  const errorMessage = () => {
    console.log("Login error");
  };

  const logOut = () => {        
    setProfile(undefined); //I am not expert, so setting undefined
    localStorage.removeItem("user");
    googleLogout();
  };
```

> Usage

```
  {localStorage.getItem("user") ? (
    <Span>
      <Button onClick={logOut}>
        {t("Logout")}
      </Button>
    </Span>
  ) : (
    <GoogleLogin onSuccess={responseMessage} onError={errorMessage} />
  )}
```

Only sad part is google login button alignment, which is a different problem

[image]