# How to know userID of logged user with JWT?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

I want to know the userId with this route using or not the JWT Token each time I want to add on my database the elements linked which I click :

```
    .post(parseArticle, (req,res) => {


      db.query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id_article = ?", [[ req.articleId]], function (err,result) {
        if (err) throw err;


        let token = req.headers['x-access-token'] || req.headers['authorization']  || req.cookies.token;
        if (!!token && token.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
          token = token.slice(7, token.length);
        }

        if (token) {

          jwt.verify(token, 'RANDOM_TOKEN_SECRET', (err, decoded) => {
            if (err) {
              return res.status(401).json('token_not_valid');
            } else {
              req.userId = decoded.userId
              db.query("INSERT INTO panier_item(id_article,image,name,description,price,iduser) VALUES (?)", [[req.articleId,result[0].image, result[0].name, result[0].description, result[0].price, req.userId]], function (err,result)
              {if (err) throw err;})
              req.decoded = decoded;
            }

      // on envoie l'article ajouté à l'utilisateur
      res.status(200).json({message: "Good!"})
    })}})})
```

but I always get NULL when I want to INSERT INTO that req.userId :
`"INSERT INTO panier_item(id_article,image,name,description,price,iduser) VALUES (5, 'https://www.cdiscount.com/pdt2/6/0/6/1/300x300/spo4013771089606/rw/sponeta-table-tennis-de-table-table-ping-pong-co.jpg', 'Table de ping-pong', 'Le moment de détente que tout le monde attend entre deux pauses !', '400', NULL)"`

Thanks you,

Comment: Weirdly, it worked... I haven't none userId in my token sended, so I log out and login again...  It worked and it's a bit strange. I have used the parseInt(token).userId instead of req.userId on INSERT INTO . Therefore, I've removed the part of jwt.verify PS: ParseInt method ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/38552302/18716582 )